# How Firestore Snapshotlistener receives events, when multiple changes applied to a document & event receiving device has not internet available

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two devices. Device1 has internet connection, Device2 doesnot have internet.

in Device1 i am changing state of a document multiple times on firestore & listening the same in Device1(No internet). How Firebase SnapshotListener will triiger onEvent() when Device1 get internet access.

It will give the last changed document data.
I want previous data changes also, how can i get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A document listener is not guaranteed to get all changes to that document over time.  Listeners merely **synchronize** data based on what it sees to be the current contents of that document.  As long as a device has a good internet connection, it will eventually receive the latest contents of a document, but not necessarily each individual update.

If you need a record of everything that might have changed in a document, you will need to record that yourself in one document for each change that others need to know about.  The others will need to read that history of changes and decide what to do with them.